# C++. Ошибка: allocating an object of abstract class type 'JIntent'

Tags: c++

Ошибка:

> allocating an object of abstract class type 'JIntent'

Как исправить?

```
Intent *JIntent; //Где-то в main.h

//menu.cpp
Intent = new JIntent(this); //Ошибка
```

---

```
class TestClass
{
    public:
        JIntent *MyIntent;
        JService *MyService;
        virtual int FuncClass() = 0;
};
```

А потом

```
int TestClass::FuncClass() {
    MyIntent = new JIntent(this);
    MyService = new JService(this);

}
```

Вот так пробовал.. Та же ошибка.. Я просто не догоняю.

Comment: Очевидно, не нужно конструировать абстрактный класс. _Ваш Кэп_.

Comment: `virtual int FuncClass() = 0;` - означает чисто-виртуальную функцию, что делает класс *абстрактным*. Экземпляр абстрактного класса создавать нельзя.

Comment: @ixSci стоит заметить, что ТС создает не экземпляр `TestClass`, а `JIntent`. В общем, в самом вопросе уже каши намешано.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> new JIntent(this);
> ```

Наследника создавать. Ясно же написано, что инстансы абстрактных классов создавать нельзя. На то они и абстрактные.